# BottomNavigationView changing it's programmed configuration

Tags: java, android

I'm using a library to turn fonts into icons, so I can use in my botton navigation menu icons, but they disappear when I touch them (I haven't set any icon in my xml)

FontIconTypefaceHolder.init(getAssets(), "fontawesome.ttf");

```
    Drawable[] icons = new Drawable[] {
            FontIconDrawable.inflate(getBaseContext(), R.xml.ic_collection),
            FontIconDrawable.inflate(getBaseContext(), R.xml.ic_persona),
            FontIconDrawable.inflate(getBaseContext(), R.xml.ic_trending),
            FontIconDrawable.inflate(getBaseContext(), R.xml.ic_explore),
            FontIconDrawable.inflate(getBaseContext(), R.xml.ic_events)
    };

    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) myMenu.getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
        itemView.setIcon(icons[i]);
        itemView.setShiftingMode(false);
        itemView.setChecked(false);
    }
```

How can I keep those config through the whole application? I can't also "getassets()" in my other fragments, so I can't tell if that's the problem...

Comment: The BottomNavigationView handle icons, why would you use a lib for it ?

Comment: I forgot to mencion, I'm using a lib to change a tff font character to use as a icon